# How to avoid CKeditor to load files when it's invoked

Tags: yii2, ckeditor

I use CKEditor in a modal window, so it's "invoked" when the modal is shown.

When this happens I see CKEditor try to loads files like:

```
ckeditor/lang/es.js?t=J5S8
ckeditor/styles.js?t=J5S8
ckeditor/plugins/confighelper/plugin.js?t=J5S8
ckeditor/skins/moono-lisa/editor.css
...
```

I tried to load all these files in the page, but when CKeditor is invoked it tries to load **again** more files, even the ones I already loaded.

This is a problem in my case because I use an AssetManager and Minification system in my framework (Yii2), and since everything is packed in one file, CKeditor fails when it tries to load again files.

Is there any way to preload everything that CKeditor will need, in order to have the Assets and Minify process working well ?

My CKEditor config is:

```
         CKEDITOR.replace('#editor', {
            customConfig: '',
            height: 200,
            language: 'es',
            extraPlugins: 'confighelper',
            removePlugins: 'elementspath',
            resize_enabled: false,
            toolbarLocation: 'top',
            toolbar: [
                { name: 'styles', items: [ 'Format' ] },
                { name: 'basicstyles', groups: [ 'basicstyles', 'cleanup' ], items: [ 'Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline' ] },
                { name: 'links', items: [ 'Link', 'Unlink' ] },             
                { name: 'clipboard', groups: [ 'clipboard', 'undo' ], items: [ 'Undo', 'Redo' ] },
                { name: 'editing', groups: [ 'spellchecker' ], items: [ 'Scayt' ] },
                { name: 'tools', items: [ 'Maximize' ] },
            ]

        });
```

Comment: What ckeditor extension are you using?

Comment: I edited the question with all the editor configuration

Comment: Does CKEditor not initiate? What is the problem caused by it? 
CKEditor autodetects, that is is already initiated - meaning throws JS error into console, but should work normally. To answer properly your question you'd need to specify the way of loading CKEditor assets. E.g. are you loading modal content dynamically via `renderAjax($view)` or modal content is included along with the view via render($view)? One solution could be loading CKEditor assets only once and load modal content without JS links.

Comment: it's a renderAjax view, and when the javascript describe above runs , then CKeditor try to load a lot of new files

Comment: add the code you are using to load the view and the name of the yii2 extension that you are using in the view to load the editor ? or are you using the javascript only to load the editor? also specify the version of the editor you are using